# VBA to copy website data by putting details one by one

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this website and i have been trying to create an function which collects `ID Number` from `Col"A"` and its `Date of initiation` in `Col"B"`.

then adds the Sum of two boxes into 3rd one like below image.

after that it will go for the result it will be like

If the individual gets first dose then insert in Col"C" "1st Dose Done" If the individual gets second dose then insert in Col"D" "second dose done" if the individual has not taken both or single dose result will be empty.

then go for next until Col"A" used range. I have tried to create function but could not, Your help will be appreciated in this regards.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Newfunction()

    Const Url$ = ""

    Dim IdNumber As String, openDate As Date, LogData As Worksheet
    Set LogData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    IdNumber = LogData.Cells(2, "A").Value
    openDate = LogData.Cells(2, "B").Value

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim IDdata As Object, puttdate As Object, submitbut As String
        Set IDdata = .document.getElementsByName("checkEligibilityForm:cnic")(0)
        Set puttdate = .document.getElementsByName("checkEligibilityForm:issueDate_input")(0)
        Set submitbut = .document.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0).innerText

        
        IDdata.Value = IdNumber
        puttdate.Value = Format(openDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        submitbut.Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)
        Debug.Print .document.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you get an error that you can't resolve? If so, what's the error and which line? If not then which part is not working exactly? Please put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, `oLogin` and `oPassword` are neither declared nor set to anything,

Comment: Yes when i run the code it paste the ID Number accurately but it paste the date into this format `Tue Dec 18 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` instead of this `20/12/2013`, then how to sum the boxes to get the result in sheet. I have changed them.

Comment: Try `puttdate.Value = Format(openDate,"dd/mm/yyyy")`. Since you know how to target an element by name, try targeting the 2 numbers' element first then access its `innerText` property. You will need to do some processing in order to do the math.

Comment: Yeah Thanks  now its working for id and date, i am unable to get the name how ti find them by (what is the name of the boxes) name or reference. Any example for the processing.

Comment: Most elements dont have name attribute so you need to find them using `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementByID` (or combination of them) or if you know how to use XPath, `querySelector`. Inspect the html and find out how to target the element in the easiest way @Valiant

Comment: sorry I can't give you an example on how to process since that is dependent on what `innerText` provide so worry about that after you managed to target the element.

Comment: I have been trying to find since couple of hours Boxes reference but no success but with inspect HTML it selects the complete box including `ID - Date - Boxes - Submit button` does not select single element.

Comment: Try assigning a string variable to `.document.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0).innerText` then `Debug.Print` and think on how to process it. Once you got the sum then set a variable to `.document.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)` like what you did for `IDdata` and `puttdate` and assign its `Value` property to the sum

Comment: Thanks for further guidance. I have updated the code above and receiving an error `Object Required` on line  `Set submitbut = .document.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0).innerText` I do not have much expertise dealing with VBA please ignore my mistake.

Comment: `innerText` property returns a `String` which is why I specifically said "assigning a _string_ variable" in my previous comment

Comment: I have posted an answer, please test it out! If it works, post a new question for whatever issue you got into in the result page (and provide the html codes for the relevant section because it's not possible for us to get to that page unless you provide a credential which I strongly encouraged you not to do so). @Valiant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below - This should do the following:

1. Enter the CNIC
2. Enter the date
3. Answer the Captcha question
4. Click the button and the page should load.

As I can't proceed to the result page, I can't guarantee that it will produce the result page so please test it out with a proper data to see if it works. I have also  tried to explain what each block of codes is doing in the comment.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Newfunction()
    Const Url As String = "https://nims.nadra.gov.pk/nims/certificate"
    
    Dim LogData As Worksheet
    Set LogData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim IdNumber As String
    Dim openDate As Date
    IdNumber = LogData.Cells(2, "A").Value
    openDate = LogData.Cells(2, "B").Value
    
    Set LogData = Nothing
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .navigate Url
        
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        .Visible = True

        Dim ieDoc As Object
        Set ieDoc = .Document
    End With
        
    'Enter the CNIC
    Dim IDdata As Object
    Set IDdata = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:cnic")
    If Not IDdata Is Nothing Then IDdata.Value = IdNumber
    Set IDdata = Nothing
    
    'Enter Date
    Dim puttdate As Object
    Set puttdate = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:issueDate_input")
    If Not puttdate Is Nothing Then puttdate.Value = Format(openDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Set puttdate = Nothing
    
    'Answering the captcha question
    'Split the innerText to string array to determine the equation
    
    Dim captchaQns As Object
    Set captchaQns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0)
    If Not captchaQns Is Nothing Then
        Dim mathEq() As String
        mathEq = Split(captchaQns.innerText, " ")
        Set captchaQns = Nothing
        
        'mathEq(0) = first number
        'mathEq(1) = math operator
        'mathEq(2) = second number
            
        If IsNumeric(mathEq(0)) Then
            Dim firstNum As Long
            firstNum = CLng(mathEq(0))
            
            If IsNumeric(mathEq(2)) Then
                Dim secondNum As Long
                secondNum = CLng(mathEq(2))
                
                'Select Case statement used here in case you encounter other form of math question (e.g. - X /), expand cases to cater for other scenario
                Dim mathAnswer As Long
                Select Case mathEq(1)
                    Case "+": mathAnswer = firstNum + secondNum
                End Select
            End If
        End If
            
        If mathAnswer <> 0 Then
            'Enter the answer to the box
            Dim captchaAns As Object
            Set captchaAns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)
            If Not captchaAns Is Nothing Then captchaAns.Value = mathAnswer
            Set captchaAns = Nothing
            
            'Get the submit button element, remove "disabled" attribute to allow clicking
            Dim submitBtn As Object
            Set submitBtn = ieDoc.getElementsByName("checkEligibilityForm:j_idt79")(0)
            submitBtn.removeAttribute "disabled"
            submitBtn.Click
            Set submitBtn = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Valiant This feels like a new question (and also one which you have not provided any code attempt). Assuming that you have not try yet, can you try it out first then submit a new question if you are stuck? Hint: There is only 1 `table` element in the result page, so use `getElementsByTagName` to get the `table` then look for `tr` within the `table`, I suppose checking the `Length` property will tell you whether there are 1 or 2 doses then loop through `tr` (skip the first `tr`) and access `td` element in each `tr` for your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint i will search and try my best.

Comment: @Valiant Good luck! Don't be stressed from the need of targetting so many elements, just focus on getting one element correct first then work on the next. Use `Debug.Print` 
property `.Length` and `.innerText` to help you visualise what did your code capture.

Comment: @Valiant Now I do need the ID and date, can you provide it? It's late so I like to get this done asap